# minifyEnabled and string concatenation

Tags: android, minify, string-concatenation

I have the following in my code`stringOne + "_" + stringTwo`. It works fine in debug mode, but as soon as I release the apk (minfiy is enabled) I will have the following: `stringOnedstringTwo`. Please mind the **d** char in the middle instead of **_**.

If I replace the string concatenation `stringOne + '_' + stringTwo` everything works fine, even with release APK. I never seen this issue before, could someone tell me why minify is messing with "_" ?

*I know this related to minifyEnabled true , because if I turn it off release APK would work with original solution too.*